# How can I load all images from images folder and display randomly in the screen in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to load images all randomly from images folder and display on the screen, when the user click in the image I want to show other image from folder images randomly.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// Import all images from the images folder
const images = [
  require('./images/image1.jpg'),
  // Add more images here...
];

export default function App() {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(images[0]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    const randomImage = images[randomIndex];
    setImageSrc(randomImage);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick}>
        <Image source={imageSrc} style={styles.image} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```